# Hudson Android multi-configuration test project can't find test results - "No test report files were found. Configuration error?"

Tags: android, testing, hudson

I have android test project that i've integrated into the Hudson. I have created a free-style software project with next settings : 
1. **Source Code Management** - custom workspace
2. **Run an Android emulator during build** : 
* Android OS Version: 4.0.3
* Screen density: 240
* Screen resolution: WVGA
* Device locale: en_US
* SD card size: 16M
3. **Invoke Ant**: 
Target: all clean emma debug install test
Build File: workspace/Project/build.xml
4. **Post-build Actions**
* Archive the artifacts: **/*test-TEST.xml
* Publish JUnit test result report: **/*test-TEST.xml
* Record Emma coverage report: **/coverage.xml
* Record fingerprints of files to track usage: **/*test-TEST.xml
Here's build.xml file part that covers my ant target:

```
    <!-- version-tag: custom -->
    <target name="test" depends="-test-project-check"
                description="Runs tests from the package defined in test.package property">

        <property name="tested.project.absolute.dir" location="${tested.project.dir}" />

        <property name="test.runner" value="android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner" />

        <!-- Application package of the tested project extracted from its manifest file -->
        <xpath input="${tested.project.absolute.dir}/AndroidManifest.xml"
                expression="/manifest/@package" output="tested.manifest.package" />
        <xpath input="AndroidManifest.xml"
                expression="/manifest/@package" output="manifest.package" />

        <property name="emma.dump.file"
                value="/data/data/${tested.manifest.package}/coverage.ec" />

        <if condition="${emma.enabled}">
            <then>
                <echo>WARNING: Code Coverage is currently only supported on the emulator and rooted devices.</echo>
                <run-tests-helper emma.enabled="true">
                    <extra-instrument-args>
                        <arg value="-e" />
                           <arg value="coverageFile" />
                           <arg value="${emma.dump.file}" />
                    </extra-instrument-args>
                </run-tests-helper>
                <echo>Downloading coverage file into project directory...</echo>
                <exec executable="${adb}" failonerror="true">
                    <arg line="${adb.device.arg}" />
                    <arg value="pull" />
                    <arg value="${emma.dump.file}" />
                    <arg value="coverage.ec" />
                </exec>
                <echo>Extracting coverage report...</echo>
                <emma>
                    <report sourcepath="${tested.project.absolute.dir}/${source.dir}"
                                      verbosity="${verbosity}">
                        <!-- TODO: report.dir or something like should be introduced if necessary -->
                        <infileset dir=".">
                            <include name="coverage.ec" />
                            <include name="coverage.em" />
                        </infileset>
                        <!-- TODO: reports in other, indicated by user formats -->
                        <html outfile="${basedir}/coverage/coverage.html" />
                        <xml outfile="${basedir}/coverage/coverage.xml" />
                   </report>
                </emma>
                <echo>Cleaning up temporary files...</echo>
                <delete file="coverage.ec" />
                <delete file="coverage.em" />
                <echo>Saving the report file in ${basedir}/coverage/coverage.html</echo>
            </then>
            <else>
                <run-tests-helper />
            </else>
        </if>
        <mkdir dir="${basedir}/junit-results" />
        <echo>Base dir is ${basedir}</echo>
        <exec executable="${adb}" failonerror="true" dir="${basedir}/junit-results">
            <arg line="${adb.device.arg}" />
            <arg value="pull" />
            <arg value="/data/data/${tested.manifest.package}/files/" />
        </exec>
    </target>    
    <import file="${sdk.dir}/tools/ant/build.xml" />

</project>
```

Now, this project works fine and i get both emma coverage and test results, but when i configured multi-configuration project with the same options, except for android emulator i set different variables with os, density and screen resolution, i got stuck with one error -

```
test:
     [echo] WARNING: Code Coverage is currently only supported on the emulator and rooted devices.
     [echo] Running tests ...
     [exec] 
     [exec] com.mobclix.android.externaltestharness.test.UnitActivityTest:.
     [exec] Test results for PolideaInstrumentationTestRunner=.
     [exec] Time: 25.122
     [exec] 
     [exec] OK (1 test)
     [exec] 
     [exec] 
     [exec] Generated code coverage data to /data/data/com.mobclix.android.externaltestharness/coverage.ec
     [echo] Downloading coverage file into project directory...
     [exec] 355 KB/s (2043 bytes in 0.005s)
     [echo] Extracting coverage report...
     [echo] Cleaning up temporary files...
   [delete] Deleting: /Users/biercoff/Work/Workspace/HarnessExternalTest/coverage.ec
   [delete] Deleting: /Users/biercoff/Work/Workspace/HarnessExternalTest/coverage.em
     [echo] Saving the report file in /Users/biercoff/Work/Workspace/HarnessExternalTest/coverage/coverage.html
     [echo] Base dir is /Users/biercoff/Work/Workspace/HarnessExternalTest
     [exec] pull: building file list...
     [exec] pull: /data/data/com.mobclix.android.externaltestharness/files/com.mobclix.android.externaltestharness.test-TEST.xml -> ./com.mobclix.android.externaltestharness.test-TEST.xml
     [exec] 1 file pulled. 0 files skipped.
     [exec] 40 KB/s (499 bytes in 0.012s)

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 1 minute 20 seconds
$ /Users/biercoff/.hudson/tools/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb disconnect localhost:53830
[android] Stopping Android emulator
[android] Archiving emulator log
$ /Users/biercoff/.hudson/tools/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb kill-server
Recording fingerprints
Recording test results
No test report files were found. Configuration error?
Archiving artifacts
Description set: 
Emma: looking for coverage reports in the provided path: /Users/biercoff/Work/Workspace/HarnessExternalTest/coverage/coverage.xml
Emma: found 1 report files: 
          /Users/biercoff/Work/Workspace/HarnessExternalTest/coverage/coverage.xml
Emma: stored 1 report files in the build folder: /Users/biercoff/.hudson/jobs/MulitTestHarnessProject/configurations/axis-density/240/axis-os/4.0.3/axis-resolution/WVGA/builds/2012-05-18_17-26-05/emma
Emma: Coverage: Classes 21/39 (54%). Methods 40/128 (31%). Blocks 833/2928 (28%). Lines 154.5/528 (29%). 
[DEBUG] Skipping watched dependency update for build: MulitTestHarnessProject/density=240,os=4.0.3,resolution
```

For emma coverage i had to change path in Hudson into  /Users/biercoff/Work/Workspace/HarnessExternalTest/coverage/coverage.xml to make it work, 
but when i tried to do the same thing for Junit test results, Hudson refused to "see" it. File is in the project folder under junit-results folder, but everytime i run new build, i get the same *No test report files were found. Configuration error?* error message. Tried many variations, but no luck. I'm missing probably something really tiny. Could somebody help me, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hudson searches for jUnit test results relative to its workspace. And you can't specify an absolute path (I've been using Hudson/Jenkins for more than a year and still not sure why not). So in your case it is looking only at things that are deeper in the directory level than the workspace. Now, for a multi-congiguration project the workspace does not start at the top level, but deeper - it includes axes names (e.g.: `workspace_root/AXIS1_NAME/AXIS1_VAL...`). But your tests are located *up the directory tree* from that workspace. You have to *copy* them in a build step into `${WORKSPACE}` and then Hudson will be able to publish them.